# Javascript Remove from array if empty

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array looking like this:

```
var testArray = [
    {"cid": "1234567"},
    {"cid": "892345"},
    {"cid": ""},
    {"cid": "8267783"},
    {},
    {"cid": "096873"},
];
```

How do I remove, either before a for loop or when looping, where cid = "" and where is empty {}

I tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; testArray.length; i++){

    if(testArray.cid && testArray.cid != ""){

    }

}
```

This didn't work :-/ Got this error: Cannot read property "cid" from undefined

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You just missing the `index` of item `if( testArray[i].cid )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you will use `splice()` during the loop. You need to decrease   `i` by `1`
A better way of doing this using `filter()`. Below I showed both methods.
And for checking empty object `{}` you should compare `Object.key(obj).length` with `0`

```js
var testArray = [
    {"cid": "1234567"},
    {"cid": "892345"},
    {"cid": ""},
    {"cid": "8267783"},
    {},
    {"cid": "096873"},
];
//doesnot mutates the original array.
let result = testArray.filter(x => Object.keys(x).length !== 0 && x.cid !== '');

//original array will be change after this loop
for(let i = 0;i<testArray.length;i++){
  if(Object.keys(testArray[i]).length ===0 || testArray[i].cid === ''){
    testArray.splice(i,1);
    i--;
  }
}
console.log(testArray)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out undesired data.

```js
var testArray = [
    {"cid": "1234567"},
    {"cid": "892345"},
    {"cid": ""},
    {"cid": "8267783"},
    {},
    {"cid": "096873"},
];
console.log(testArray.filter(arr => arr.cid))
```

Comment: You code will remove the objects with `cid` will be `true`,`0`,`undefined`,`null`. And OP only asked for `''`

Comment: Super, but just in case... Is there a way I can accomplish this without the use of filter?

Comment: @Mansa see my answer I also showed the way with `filter()` using simple loops

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove ALL empty values ("", null, undefined and 0):

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e){return e});
```

To remove empty values and Line breaks:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e){ return e.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")});
```

Example

```
arr = ["hello","",null,undefined,1,100," "]  
arr.filter(function(e){return e});
```

return

```
["hello", 1, 100, " "]
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var testArray = [
    {"cid": "1234567"},
    {"cid": "892345"},
    {"cid": ""},
    {"cid": "8267783"},
    {},
    {"cid": "096873"},
];

testArray = testArray.filter(item=> Object.keys(item).length && item["cid"]);
console.log(testArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added a post filter function for completeness.Vote for HolyDragon tho.

```js
var testArray = [
    {"cid": "1234567"},
    {"cid": "892345"},
    {"cid": ""},
    {"cid": "8267783"},
    {},
    {"cid": "096873"},
];

testArray.filter(i => i.cid)
         .forEach(elem => {
  // do my code post filter
  console.log(elem.cid);
});
```